# Uploading image as base 64 string webservice response getting as html tags in iOS

Tags: ios, image, base64

I am uploading image along with user id to my server. So, i converted image into base 64 string. After conversion, i am sending to server along with user id. I have checked many forums for my isssue, but hopefully not helped me. I am using below code to sending server
In **didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo** delegate method

```
        NSData *webData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage,90);
        NSLog(@"webData -->%@",webData);

        NSString *strEncoded = [Base64 encode:webData];
        NSLog(@"strEncoded -->%@",strEncoded);

       NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://"]; //url

       // NSString *base64ImageString = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:kNilOptions];  // iOS 7+

        NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = @{@"user_id" : userIdString,
                                         @"Image"    : strEncoded,
                                         };
        NSError *error;
        NSData *httpBody = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary options:0 error:&error];
        NSAssert(httpBody, @"dataWithJSONObject error: %@", error);

        NSMutableURLRequest *request2 = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url2];
        [request2 setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request2 setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request2 setHTTPBody:httpBody];
        NSLog(@"request2 -->%@",request2);
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request2 queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
            if (!data) {
                NSLog(@"sendAsynchronousRequest error: %@", connectionError);
                return;
            }

            // use the `data` result here, e.g.

            NSString *responseString2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"responseString2 = %@", responseString2);
        }];
```

my request is successfully going to server, but i am getting response as below (html tags which is not correct response)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

etc some html tags, but i need to get server response as json data, server side everything is fine. they are telling my side problem in code.
I have tried many ways, but nothing useful to me. Please anyonce can give your valuable suggestions to me. Thanks in Advanced!

Comment: @ give me url and body i have rest client i will check tell u

Comment: this kind of problem i faced i will tell u server side is wrong or our side..

Comment: hi @Mahesh thanks for your reply, pls give ur email id , i will send data and url to ur mail